# How to import strftime() and strptime() in Python IDLE

Tags: python

I tried to make a result that can show "Night club" on Staurday, "Blue Monday" on Monday, and "No way" on the other days.

The below is my code.

```
from datetime import strftime

today = datetime.strptime("date_string, %A")

if today == 'Saturday':
    print('Night club')

elif today == 'Monday':
    print('Blue Monday')
else:
    print('No way')
```

The system said that "cannot import name 'strftime' from 'datetime'", how to revise the code?

Comment: `strftime` and `strptime` are _methods_ on the `date`, `time` and `datetime` _classes_ exposed by the `datetime` _module_, you can't import them directly.

Comment: Thank you very much.
I will try it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comment said, `strftime()` and `strptime()` are methods of classes, rather than functions which you can import directly. So what you need to import is the relevant class.

In your case, `strptime()` is likely not the thing you need, you are not going turn a `date_string` (which is not given in your code) to a `datetime` object, but instead opposite, turning a `datetime` object to a weekday string.

`strftime()` can be use but it's not neccessary, you can use `isoweekday()` or `weekday()` method in `date` and `datetime` classes, they return the day of the week as an integer, one from 1-7 and another from 0-6.

As you don't need time information, I will choose the `date` class here:

```
# import the date class
from datetime import date

# use today() to get today date and use isoweekday() to get week day integer(1-7)
today = date.today().isoweekday()

if today == 6:
    print('Night club')
elif today == 1:
    print('Blue Monday')
else:
    print('No way')
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I will try it !!

So isoweekday() or weekday() is also a method of classes?

Answer (score 1):

Because `strftime` is an instance method of the `datetime` class, you need to import `datetime` from the `datetime` module first. Then, you can use its `strftime` method:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strftime()
```